# Preventing ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T> from outofmemory Exception

Tags: java, queue, out-of-memory

When working with ConcurrentLinkedQueue, how can I limit the size of the Queue. Is it possible that it will through outofmemory exception ?

Answer (score 5):

The size of a [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) is unbounded, so if producers are putting in items faster than consumers can remove them, eventually it will eat up your memory indeed. If you want to limit the size of the queue, try a blocking queue, such as [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) or [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) instead. The size of the first can be optionally bounded, while the second is always bounded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, However I used ConcurrentLinkedQueue since it is concurrent, Are you suggesting unconcurrent classes that will require me to add synchronization when accessing these variables?

Comment: @Youval, all `BlockingQueue` implementations are thread-safe, as declared in [the API docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

Comment: However blocking a thread could affect overall application performance in highly concurrent applications. So there are cons and pros.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit late on this one, but you can always set up an upper bound and when exceeded, your method will consume one token to make room for the next one and so on.